I am facing this error, "ValueError: embedded null character". Here, I was trying to load multiple csv files
I am facing this error, "ValueError: embedded null character". Here, I was trying to load multiple csv files. When I encountered this error.
Here before this I have put paths into a list for csv files (23) and stored it in a list called csv_files. Then looping through it to create and merge them but before that I encounter the error ""ValueError: embedded null character". Help me and let me know how should I handle this error?
My code:
# empty list to store dataframes
all_data = []
# Loop through each CSV file and read it into a dataframe
for file in csv_files:
  df = pd.read_csv(file)
  all_data.append(df)
# Concatenate all dataframes into a single dataframe
final_df = pd.concat(all_data, ignore_index=True)
final_df.info()

Even tried this way:
import glob
import pandas as pd

files = glob.glob("D:\Coding\0001 RE-CT\DataSets*.csv")
dfs = [pd.read_csv(f, header=None, sep=";") for f in files]

salesdata = pd.concat(dfs,ignore_index=True)

but it returns -  scandir: embedded null character in path.
I was expecting to load and merge the datasets. But then idk how to resolve this error.
